# Notation in Atiyah-Macdonald, Chapter 3, Exercise 21.iv

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

They start with $f: A \rightarrow B$,  a ring homomorphism, $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $A$, and $S = A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Then they ask to deduce that the subspace $f^{*-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p} B_{\mathfrak{p}}) = \mathrm{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_A B)$, where $k(\mathfrak{p})$ is the residue field of the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Now I am confused about two things:

1. What is $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\mathfrak{p} B_{\mathfrak{p}}$?  Is $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ = $f(S)^{-1}B$, and $\mathfrak{p} B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ = $(S^{-1}\mathfrak{p})^e$ through $S^{-1}A \rightarrow f(S)^{-1}B$?  Is there a standard convention on how to write these that I am not aware of?  I am just starting out in graduate algebra.
2. Should I show that  $B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p} B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $k(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_A B$ are isomorphic as rings? How do i put a ring structure on $k(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_A B$?

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are commutative $A$-algebras, then $B\otimes_A C$ is also an $A$-algebra vis $(b\otimes c)(b'\otimes c')=bb'\otimes cc'$.

Comment: The ring homomorphism $f: A \to B$ makes $B$ an $A$-module. The notation $B_p$ is thus a special case of the localization of an $A$-module at a prime ideal of $A$.

Comment: @Malkoun But that will just make it an A-module.  Since we are talking about its Spec, it needs to have a ring structure as well.  And is $pB_p$ just the regular submodule when $B_p$ is considered as an $A-module$?  But hold on, don't we need it to be an ideal (i.e. $B_p$ module) in the ring $B_p$ in order to have ring structure on the quotient?

Comment: You make a valid point. Basically, they are probably abusing notation somewhere. I will try to help a bit later, if I can get a hold of a copy of that book.

Comment: Check out extension and contraction of ideals on wikipedia in the page on ideals. They refer to AM proposition 3.16.

Comment: The set they are asking about is the set of all prime ideals $P$ of $B$ which contain $p^e$ and intersect trivially with $f(A \setminus p)$. It remains to check the homeomorphism part. I know you only asked about notation though.

Answer (score 1):

1. $B_p:=f(S)^{−1}B$ and $pB_{p}:=f(p)B_{p}=f(S)^{−1}p^e$
2. $k(p)⊗_{A}B≅A_{p}/pA_{p}⊗_{A}B≅A_{p}⊗_{A}A/p⊗_{A}B≅A_{p}⊗_{A}B/pB≅B_p/pB_p$ as $A$-modules and rings (For the isomorphisms, we used some properties of tensor products, e.g. exercise 2 on page 31, Proposition 3.5 on page 39 of Introduction to Commutative Algebra by M.F. Atiyah, I.G. MacDonald.)

Comment: Sorry I am seeing your answer only now. I have a few questions:

a) Is $pA_p = S^{-1}p$ then?  Why is it named this way, and not just $S^{-1}p$? When we treat $A_p$ as an A-module, then we get an A- submodule $pA_p$; is it the same as the ideal $S^{-1}p$ (an $A_p$ module, so also is an A-module).

b) Same question about $pB_p$

c) How did you get the last isomorphism in 2)?  I understand you're using the prop 3.5 but that should give you the module $S^{-1}(B/pB)$. Why is the same as $B/pB$?

d) Is the ring structure on every intermediate object from the tensor product of algebras?